# Parse Dynamic Json Objects in gson

Tags: java, android, gson, json

I have json structure like this,how I parse the json with help of Gson.I need to store the key values in json object,I tried many example related to dynamic array but dynamic json array without square brace I cannot parse using Gson.Any Solutions or need to do Manual Json Parse?If any one feel duplicate comment the answer below.

```
{ "Result":[[
      "Title",
      {
        "0": 1323,
        "1": 3358,
        "2": 2123,
        "3": 8536,
        "4": 1399,
        "5": 9303,
        "7": 9732,
        "8": 3433,
        "9": 1383
      }
    ],[
      "Title",
      {
        "0": 1323,
        "1": 3358,
        "2": 2123,
        "3": 8536,
      }
    ]]}
```

Comment: In your Json data did Title is required... or any thing like `Title:xyz`

Comment: @Don'tBenegative "Title" is a object with no key,not like you mentioned.

Comment: So is it necessary or not to view in your application

Comment: @Don'tBenegative I need to store all data in object

Comment: Please post either the error message you're receiving or describe the incorrect behavior along with the code causing it.

Comment: @appukrb - Did you review my answer? Does it successfully parse the data?

Comment: @nickb thanks for your answer,but I found a simple way to parse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start, your JSON causes an exception to be thrown because it is invalid - You have an extra comma at the end of the last value in the second example. `"3": 8536,` should be `"3": 8536`.

After fixing that, this should be a simple task provided you define your objects correctly. Here is what I came up with:

```
public class Results {
    @SerializedName("Result")
    List<Result> results;
}

public class Result {
    String title;
    Map<String, Integer> results;
}
```

From there, the `Result` class needs to be deserialized in a special fashion, since the fields in the `Result` class do not directly map to entries in the JSON. Instead, we need to pull off the first and second elements of the `JsonArray` that is contained within each `Result`, and parse it accordingly. That looks like this:

```
public class ResultDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Result> {

    @Override
    public Result deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonArray array = json.getAsJsonArray();

        Result result = new Result();
        result.title = array.get(0).getAsString();

        result.results = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
        for(Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : array.get(1).getAsJsonObject().entrySet()) {
            result.results.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().getAsInt());
        }

        return result;
    }   
}
```

Note that my example omits error checking. Finally, register this deserializer, and you should be all set:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Result.class, new ResultDeserializer()).create();

Results results = gson.fromJson(json, Results.class);

for(Result r : results.results) {
    System.out.println("Title = " + r.title);
    for(Entry<String, Integer> entry : r.results.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("\t " + entry.getKey() + " -> " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
Title = Title
     0 -> 1323
     1 -> 3358
     2 -> 2123
     3 -> 8536
     4 -> 1399
     5 -> 9303
     7 -> 9732
     8 -> 3433
     9 -> 1383
Title = Title
     0 -> 1323
     1 -> 3358
     2 -> 2123
     3 -> 8536
```

I'll leave it to the OP to implement the reverse, that is a serializer for `Result` to produce the same results.

Comment: Results results = gson.fromJson(json, Results.class);
in this line what is json?

Answer (score 1):

Found simple way to parse above json using **Nested Map** in **Gson**

**Result.java**

```
public class Result {
    @SerializedName("formatted_facet_fields")
    Map<String,Map<String,String>> formatted_facet_fields;
}
```

in response receiving side

```
 Gson  gson=new Gson();
 Result result = gson.fromJson(json_response, Result.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can parse nested json object.

```
if (!exists) {
        keys = json.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            nextKeys = (String) keys.next();
            try {

                if (json.get(nextKeys) instanceof JSONObject) {

                    if (exists == false) {
                        getKey(json.getJSONObject(nextKeys), key);
                    }

                } else if (json.get(nextKeys) instanceof JSONArray) {
                    JSONArray jsonarray = json.getJSONArray(nextKeys);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        String jsonarrayString = jsonarray.get(i).toString();
                        JSONObject innerJSOn = new JSONObject(jsonarrayString);

                        if (exists == false) {
                            getKey(innerJSOn, key);
                        }

                    }

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        }
```

For complete understanding checkout below: Code Explanation : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjZqLUGCWxo

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).